# What's the difference between: ". [script]" or "source [script]", "bash [script] or $SHELL [script]", and "./ [script]" or "[script]"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dot-source

I know that `source` and `.` do the same thing, and I would be surprised to learn if the other pairs of commands in the title don't so the same thing (because I'm running bash as my shell, `$SHELL [script]` and `bash [script]` are equivalent, right??).

So what's the difference between the three methods of executing the script? I'm asking because I just learned that sourcing a script is [NOT the exact same](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291404/why-does-bashs-source-not-need-the-execution-bit) as executing it. In a way that I didn't find obvious from running my "experiments" and reading the man pages.

**What are the other subtle differences that I couldn't find by blindly calling these functions on incredibly simple scripts that I've written?** After reading the above-linked answer, I can strongly guess that the answer to my question will be quite a simple explanation, but in a way that I'd almost never fully discover by myself.

Here's the "experiment" I did:

```
$. myScript.sh
  "This is the output to my script. I'd like to think it's original."

$source myScript.sh
  "This is the output to my script. I'd like to think it's original."

$bash myScript.sh
  "This is the output to my script. I'd like to think it's original."

$$SHELL myScript.sh
  "This is the output to my script. I'd like to think it's original."

$./myScript.sh 
  "This is the output to my script. I'd like to think it's original."

$myScript.sh 
  "This is the output to my script. I'd like to think it's original."
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`. script` and `source script` execute the contents of `script` *in the current environment*, i.e. without creating a subshell. On the upside this allows `script` to affect the current environment, for example changing environment variables or changing the current work directory. On the downside this allows `script` to affect the current environment, which is a potential security hazard.

`bash script` passes `script` to the `bash` interpreter to execute. Whatever shebang is given by `script` itself is ignored. ("Shebang" referring to the first line of `script`, which could e.g. read `#!/bin/bash`, or `#!/usr/bin/perl`, or `#!/usr/bin/awk`, to specify the interpreter to be used.)

`$SHELL script` passes `script` to *whatever is your current shell interpreter* to execute. That may, or may not, be `bash`. (The environment variable `SHELL` holds the name of your current shell interpreter. `$SHELL`, if running bash, is evaluated to `/bin/bash`, with the effect detailed in the previous paragraph.)

`./script` executes the contents of a file `script` *in the current work directory*. If there is no such file, an error is generated. The contents of `$PATH` have no effect on what happens.

`script` looks for a file `script` *in the directories listed in `$PATH`*, which may or may not include the current work directory. The first `script` found in this list of directories is executed, which may or may not be the one in your current work directory.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! So I could be running a different shell (say, csh), and STILL call `bash [script]`. The added part about the shebang was interesting! So "$SHELL [script]" will also ignore shebangs. Another thing I just realized, was that the directory I was in when running my experiments was in my $PATH variable. If it wasn't, "[script]" simply wouldn't have worked. Wow. There's a ton of differences for such a similar seeming output.

Comment: @AriSweedler: That is correct. Note that some tools *ignore* your current shell, and default to `/bin/sh` unless *explicitly* told otherwise (crontab and make, for example).

Comment: Remarks: `source` is a Bashism, `.` is POSIX; `$SHELL` might expand to something other than your shell (it's `/bin/bash` when running dash, for example).